# rclcpp::Time epochs

Tags: time, rclcpp, timestamp

I would like to get seconds, and nanoseconds from inside my node, so I have a timer_callback that executes each 100ms, to note seconds and nanoseconds of the rclcpp::Time

```
    void timer_callback() {
        rclcpp::Time t = this->now();
        cout << unsigned(t.seconds()) << '\t' << unsigned(t.nanoseconds()) << endl;
    }
```

What I get is, number of seconds since last epoch, and a uint32 representation of nanoseconds, that is actually accurate, (1sec=1e9ns), in which is measurable by chaning timer1 frequency, i.e. a diff of the nanoseconds is usable, but it does not reset each second, basically it has its own 4.2~ second epoch.

What is the epoch for nanoseconds?

Any ideas on how to get the seconds and nanoseconds to make a timestamp that is microseconds accurate?

Best Regards,
C.A.

```
[node-1] 1697373475 3482658792

[node-1] 1697373475 3982695401

[node-1] 1697373476 187537493

[node-1] 1697373476 687584889

[node-1] 1697373477 1187751915

[node-1] 1697373477 1687731420

[node-1] 1697373478 2187763841

[node-1] 1697373478 2687771385

[node-1] 1697373479 3187776990

[node-1] 1697373479 3687628969
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in the `unsigned()` cast.

Code changed to this:

```cpp
rclcpp::Time t = this->now();
std::cout << t.seconds() << '\t' << t.nanoseconds() << std::endl;
std::cout << unsigned(t.seconds()) << '\t' << unsigned(t.nanoseconds()) << std::endl;
```

Gives output:

```
1.6974e+09  1697398304675212161
1697398304  3498322817
```

Nanoseconds is not a `uint32`:

`rclcpp::Time::nanoseconds()` [returns a](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/7f7ffcf6ed1143b4d4a9e0cf248e190731b2e5f8/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/time.hpp#L178-L184) `rcl_time_point_value_t`, which is [a typedef of](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/45fc9520216013007c2d4f3bd69d778af9051aa3/rcl/include/rcl/time.h#L45-L46) an `rcutils_time_point_value_t`, which is [a typedef of](https://github.com/ros2/rcutils/blob/e276dc1fe5a0e450e53423ec71d57cbe05b129f8/include/rcutils/time.h#L47C2-L48) an `int64_t`.